# Markup on excel on mac

Tags: macos, ms-office

What is the formula on the OS X version of Excel 2016 to add a number in a column with a markup percentage in another column.

Answer (score 1):

Example:
Cell A1 contains a number,
cell B1 contains a percentage number,
so cell C1 calculates A1 plus B1 percent

The formula you type into cell C1 is `=A1*(1+B1/100)`

See also: [help page for calculating percentages in Excel 2016 for Mac.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Calculate-percentages-in-Excel-2016-for-Mac-bd25d31f-0474-4d50-a23e-a88decc17dbd)